# Phrase/expression for "growing at my own speed"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm writing the acknowledgments-section of my thesis and want to thank my academic advisor for his patience and support, and for allowing me to "grow at my own speed". I'm looking for a concise way to word the last part.

What I'm trying to say is that he did not push me or try to mold me into something that he wanted me to be, but rather gave me time and space to find and understand my own strengths, and become a good researcher

Comment: I think the phrase "he gave me [the] time and space to find and understand my own strengths" is very good.

Comment: progress at my own pace?

Comment: Or if you want something more concise, "patient" or "patience."

Answer (score 1):

[nurturing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nurturing) may be the word you're looking for.

> to support and encourage, as during the period of training or development; foster:

Comment: Hey there Brandon & welcome to *EL&U*, *nurturing* is a good answer, please include a citation for the source of all direct quotations, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could thank him for allowing *autonomy* or *self-direction*

[***autonomy***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/autonomy) / [***self-direction***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/self-direction) -

> personal independence

Answer (score 0):

Consider **hit one's stride**.

> hit one's stride (AmEng) or get into one's stride (BrEng): to begin to do something in a confident and effective way after starting slowly ([**Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/stride))